# How to add another loop to a Python nested loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

**Edited**

I am new to Python, having a problem adding a loop to a nested loop Python code.
using Python 3.8 on my windows 7 machine.

The code does when run once: it reads from multiple CSV files, row by row, and CSV file by CSV file, and uses the data from each row ( within a given range)to run the function until there is no CSV file left, each CSV file has 4 columns, all CSV files have one header each.
There are a few seconds of delay between each row reading.

since the code is just for one-time use, when you run the code again, it reads the same rows, it does not loop to read other rows.

So I want to add another loop to it, so each time you run the file somehow it remembers the last row that was used and starts from the next row.
So assume it has been set to a range of 2 rows:

the first-time run: uses row 1 and 2 to run the function
second-time run: uses row 3 and 4 to run the function, and so on

Appreciate your help to make it work.

**Example CSV**

```
img_url,desc_1 title_1,link_1
site.com/image22.jpg;someTitle;description1;site1.com
site.com/image32.jpg;someTitle;description2;site2.com
site.com/image44.jpg;someTitle;description3;site3.com
```

Here is the working code I have:

```py
from abc.zzz  import xyz
path_id_map = [
    {'path':'file1.csv', 'id': '12345678'},
    {'path':'file2.csv', 'id': '44556677'}
    {'path':'file3.csv', 'id': '33377799'}
    {'path':'file4.csv', 'id': '66221144'}]
s_id = None

for pair in path_id_map:
    with open(pair['path'], 'r') as f:
        next(f)  # skip first header line
        for _ in range(1, 3):      
            line = next(f)
            img_url, title_1, desc_1, link_1 = map(str.strip, line.split(';'))
            zzz.func1(img_url=img_url, title_1=title_1, desc_1=desc_1, 
                      link_1=link_1, B_id=B_id=pair['id'], s_id=s_id)
            time.sleep(25)
```

**** Update ****

After a few days of looking for a solution, a Code has been posted( UPDATE 2):
but there is a major problem with it.

it works the way I want only when using the print function,

I adopted my function to it but, when it runs for a second time or more, it does not loop to the next rows, (it  only does loop correctly on the last CSV file though),

the author of the code could not correct his code, I can not figure out what is wrong with it.

I checked the CSV files and tested them with the print function, they are OK.

perhaps someone helps to correct the problem or another solution altogether.

Comment: So basically you want to save some metadata about the csv file. I.e. after you read a csv, you will add a row to the csv, then in a different file you will save the line where you left off so you can start from that line again. Is that what you want?

Comment: thanks for the reply, my intention to use all data in number of CSV files row by row, by given row range and number of runs daily, I don't want to baby sit,  I don't know if it is necessary to write to the data csv file, I don't want to mess with the data csv file, I want somehow record the last used row (index) to a text file,  and every time file runs it check this text file first, for the last row index number, add one to it (last row index number+1) as the new row number to start reading the csv file.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what exactly you want, so I can't provide a great code example but I recommend reading this article about [saving and loading to a JSON file](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/). JSON is basically just python lists and dictionaries. So you can save and load dictionaries from a file quite easily. Great for saving and loading values in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I hope I have understood what you're asking. I think the below code might guide you if you adjust it a little bit for your case. You can store the number of the final line into a text file. I also assume that as a delimiter the semi-colon is used.

**UPDATE 1**:

Okay, I think I came up with this solution to your problem, hopefully. The only prerequisite to run this is to have a text file which includes the number of row you want to begin with for the **first** run (e.g. 1).

```
# define function
import csv
import time
import subprocess
import os
import itertools

# txt file that contains the number of line to start the next time
dir_txt = './'
fname_txt = 'number_of_last_line.txt'
path = os.path.join(dir_txt, fname_txt)
# assign line number to variable after reading relevant txt
with open(path, 'r', newline='') as f:
    n = int(f.read())

# define path of csv file
fpath = './file1.csv'

# open csv file
with open(fpath, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    
    # Iterate every row of csv. csv_reader row number starts from 1,
    # csv_reader generator starts from 0
    for row in itertools.islice(csv_reader, n, n+3):
        print('row {0} contains {1}'.format(csv_reader.line_num, row))
        time.sleep(3)

# Store the number of line to start the next time
n = csv_reader.line_num + 1
# Bash (or cmd) command execution, option. You can do this with python also
sh_command = 'echo {0} > {1}'.format(csv_reader.line_num, path)
subprocess.run(sh_command, shell=True)
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Here's a revision with the code working for multiple files using the input of @Error - Syntactical Remorse. The first thing you need to do is open the *metadata.json* file and insert the number of row you want to begin each file, for the **first run only**. You also need to change the file directories according to your situation.

```
# define function
def get_json_metadata(json_fpath):
    """Read json file
    Args:
        json_fpath -- string (filepath)
    Returns:
        json_list -- list"""

    with open(json_fpath, mode='r') as json_file:
        json_str = json_file.read()
        json_list = json.loads(json_str)
    return json_list

# Imports
import csv, json
import time
import os
import itertools

# json file that contains the number of line to start the next time
dir_json = './'
fname_json = 'metadata.json'
json_fpath = os.path.join(dir_json, fname_json)
# csv filenames, IDs and number of row to start reading are extracted
path_id_map = get_json_metadata(json_fpath)

# iterate over csvfiles
for nfile in path_id_map:
    print('\n------ Reading {} ------\n'.format(nfile['path']))
    with open(nfile['path'], 'r', newline='') as csvfile:

        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        
        # Iterate every row of csv. csv_reader row number starts from 1,
        # csv_reader generator starts from 0
        for row in itertools.islice(csv_reader, nfile['nrow'], nfile['nrow']+5):
            # skip empty line (list)
            if not row:
                continue
            # assign values to variables
            img_url, title_1, desc_1, link_1 = row
            B_id = nfile['id']

            print('row {0} contains {1}'.format(csv_reader.line_num, row))
            time.sleep(3)

    # Store the number of line to start the next time
    nfile['nrow'] = csv_reader.line_num

with open(json_fpath, mode='w') as json_file:
    json_str = json.dumps(path_id_map, indent=4)
    json_file.write(json_str)
```

This is how the *metadata.json* format should be:

```
[
    {
        "path": "file1.csv",
        "id": "12345678",
        "nrow": 1
    },
    {
        "path": "file2.csv",
        "id": "44556677",
        "nrow": 1
    },
    {
        "path": "file3.csv",
        "id": "33377799",
        "nrow": 1
    },
    {
        "path": "file4.csv",
        "id": "66221144",
        "nrow": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply; I could not adopt your code to mine, as you notice in my code I used multiple csv files and csv files contains multiple columns, so as I am new to Python, I could not figure it out how to adopt it to my code.

Comment: @Dave99 I just made a revision to work for multiple files and make usage of JSON metadata file as Error - Syntactical Remorse suggested

Comment: Kostas VI, Thanks for the updated code, the new codes works fine, with print function exactly the way I want it, but when I replace print with my function `zzz.func1('row {0} contains {1}'.format(csv_reader.line_num, row))` I get errors of: `No value for argument 'B_id' in unbound method call`  and  `No value for argument 'img_url' in unbound method call`  so the code does not recognize the parameters inside my function. `B_id ` value is inside the json file as id, and `img_url` is inside the CSV file. I did put `id` (B_id) value inside the CSV file ( added another column) but still not work.

Comment: Hi @Dave99 check out the code. I made another revision to fix your problem

Comment: Thanks Kostas VI, for the updated code,  I applied the updated code, I still get the same error: `func1() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'B_id' and 'img_url'`

Comment: Can you please tell i) what are your variables and ii) what is the type of each variable? Also, can you provide the first line of your function definition (i.e. `def func1(arg1, arg2, arg3):` ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, the function I use is part of github project, there is a function that I tried to make it automatic or semi automatic, [here](https://github.com/bstoilov/py3-pinterest/blob/master/examples.py) is the example files, search for the function def pin.that is what I am using.

Comment: So this is how you should call the `pin()` function:
`pin(board_id=B_id, section_id=None, image_url=img_url, description=desc_1, title=title_1, link=link_1)`

Comment: thanks for the reply, I run the code, no error and it did work, but the sequence of going to next row, did not work properly, for the testing purpose, I used 3 CSV files, and I used 2 for the range,( 2 images for each run),  the second run results was duplicate images, on Json file, first nrow is 1, second nrow is 1 and third nrow is 5. the image from last csv file was not duplicate but it did use only 1 . so instead of using 2 images at the second run, it used 1

Comment: Please tell me 1) what exactly your inputs in the `itertools.islice()` are and 2) how many lines (incl. headers)  your csv files have

Comment: thanks for reply, my csv files have one line header, I made some cleaning, and made new csv files, just in case if there is any bad CSV files.

Comment: `itertools.islice()` input data, if you mean data inside csv files, cells of data are not wrapped in any single or double quotes, all column data are semi-colon separated,  exact header line for all csv files: `image_url;description;title;link` and inside cells: image_url column: a url ends with .jpg file, title column: is title with no comma or anything else, description column: some description text with some comma, hashtags in it, about 140 to 250 characters long, column link: a usual link ends with / and for the lines of csv files, for testing I had only 6 lines of data, total 7 lines

Comment: I guess since I removed  this `print ('row {0} contains {1}'.format(csv_reader.line_num, row))` and replaced it with my function line, this code can not work properly.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense not to work with your function, since the outputs in the print() are correct. I have a sense that something is going on with your csv files or that I have misunderstood what your output should be

Comment: Thanks for your reply and concern, I will change my CSV file again, make another attempt with more data on CSV files, and less range, to see what happen, the print function alone works perfect, so it is about make it work with print function I guess. somehow inside the print function adding those parameters of actual functions.

Comment: @Dave99 Hi Dave, did you find what is the issue? In case you're satisfied by my answer, could you please vote it up?

Comment: No, so far I did not find what was is wrong with it, but thanks for your help, I will vote that up.

Comment: I tested with new CSV files, same results, I also switched the last CSV file in JSON file with the first one, and run the file once, it still gets the same result, the first 2 nrow shows: 1, and the last one stored the correct number (3), ( I used 3 CSV files in JSON file), I also tried the Print function with the same CSV files, it worked fine, it printed all cells of data, and nrow on JSON file stored right number after running the file couple of times. so the CSV files are OK, the code is configured for the Print function only. Perhaps you Kostas VI or someone else can come along and help.